# Black border appear under the bookmark bar of the chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

So what confused me recently is that my chrome started appearing a black border under the bookmark bar of the browser.It happens whenever I open my chrome and maximize the window.Even restart the chrome it still appear.It looks like:

[image]

You can see the black border is too thick(just compare it with your chrome).
Only when I reduce the window size will it disappear.It looks like:

[image]

I have thought it might have something to do with CSS but I can't get any information from the dev tools.I have also turned to chrome community forum for help.Although there is someone alse who met the same problem,none of them know the cause.

Any ideas what might be causing this?Is it a bug?

Version: Google Chrome79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) m (64-bit)

OS: win10

Comment: This is off-topic. Stack Overflow is for specific programming-related problems, not tech support. See: [help/on-topic].

Comment: Sorry for that but I can‘t get help from other place.

Comment: What, why? You can’t use superuser.com, https://support.google.com/chrome, https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/, or any one of the countless other related websites?

Comment: As an aside, try disabling the extensions you’re using?

Comment: Do you have your Windows resolution scale at 125%? The border is 'off' for me too since the last Chrome update, it's subtle but annoying. Doesn't happen for me at 100% or 150% resolution scale, only 125%.

Comment: no, the window is 100% and it still appear no matter 80%.90%,120% or other sizes

Comment: Are we talking about the same scale option? I don't mean the scale/zoom inside chrome, I mean the main windows scaling (Display Settings -> Scale and Layout)

Comment: @pjumble I also tried that.Chrome looks normal In 100%,however,the layout is too small for me,because of which I have been using 120% all the time.And it may have nothing to do with this option since I have not met this problem at the past(even using 120%).The problem happens recently.

Answer (score 0):

what happens when opening another page? does it show it there?

Try changing the theme to black or another.  see what results you get.

If it is related to google homepage only, then it's possibly something to do with getting viewport size  and then the related scaling logic.

Comment: It always appear there whenever I restart the browser,open another page or even restart my computer.

Comment: got to be related to chrome getting the viewport and then scaling it to screen, what os are using ?

Comment: using win10.I have told above.

Comment: It only appears exactly when I maximize the window.